# How to create a dataset in android?

Tags: android, database, datatable, dataset

**Brief problem statment**. 
Im trying to find the best way to offload in a dataset or datable all the rows of a pre-existing sqlite database located in the assets folder. There is a lot of tutos in the web about external database management in android but most of them only work with one column and thus using Lists instead of any kind of dataset objects.

**What I am trying to do...**. I have a table in a database, lets say that it is conformed by 50 rows and 5 columns. I need to offload all the rows and columns in a object and after that, assign that object as source of a gridview. In every gridview cell Ill show an icon (that must open an activity) and under the icon the description (extracted from the database).
If the user clicks on one of the icons, then the app will launch an activity using information extracted from the database.

I hope I was clear, but if didnt please dont hesitate in ask me more details. I dont want that you guys do my work, but some tips or "north" will help, I am open mind.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: you dont need to "load" anything, just use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

**Java - DataSet**

```
public class Dataset {
private Context context;
public static ArrayList<MenuModel> getMenuList() {
    ArrayList<MenuModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    MenuModel model = new MenuModel();
    model.setName("Samosa");
    model.setPrice("20");
    model.setItemImage(R.drawable.ic_sip);
    list.add(model);

    model = new MenuModel();
    model.setName("Vada");
    model.setItemImage(R.drawable.ic_sip);
    model.setPrice("40");
    list.add(model);

    return list;

}}
```